Are probability distributions the same as these distributions in mathematical analysis? (simple question)
Consider this definition of distributions that we see in analysis.
I have been brushing up on my probability and statistics knowledge. I already know that the term "distribution" has different semantic meanings depending on what field of mathematics you are looking at. For instance, distributions in the differential geometry are a subspace of the tangent bundle, and wholly unrelated (according to Lee) to the definition that I have linked.
I don't have a textbook like Lee's that clarifies the distinction between probability distributions and the analysis definition. Is the probability distribution also a distinct entity from this analysis definition?
A direct yes/no suffices. Thanks in advance.

Yes, different.

Certainly, distributions in analysis need not satisfy the Kolmogorov axioms (although this can usually be "fixed").  You can read about the difference (especially in terms of setting): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution .

A probability distribution has a non-negative value and a "total" maximally 1. A generalized function distribution can have any value and "total".

No, they are not the same. A probability distribution is a measure which assigns $1$ to the full space. A distribution (in the analytic sense) is an element of the dual space of some set of test functions, usually those which are smooth with compact support, or those which are Schwartz functions (in the latter case one often talks of tempered distributions).
Consider the space $\mathbb R$ and let $\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$ denote the Schwartz functions on $\mathbb R$. Every probability distribution $\mu$ is a measure. You can canonically assign to it the tempered distribution (in the analytic sense)
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}\hat\mu: \mathcal S(\mathbb R)&\to\mathbb R \\ f&\mapsto \int_{\mathbb R}f \,\mathrm d\mu.\end{split}\end{equation*}
However, not every distribution (in the analytic sense) has a measure which in the above sense induces that distribution, let alone a probability distribution. For example, consider the distribution
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
\phi: \mathcal S(\mathbb R)&\to\mathbb R \\
f &\mapsto -f'(0).
\end{split}\end{equation*}
As I will leave for you to check, there is no measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$, not even a signed one, such that $\hat\mu=\phi$.
